# How to populate dropdown data from one dropdown to another dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two dropdowns one is outside of dynamic table another one is inside of table column. now my problem is how to populate non-selected data one dropdown to another dropdown.

Which means, for example if i select one value from 1st dropdown, remaining non selected values only **Copied** to 2nd dropdown (inside dynamic table dropdown). and if i click add row, that same 2nd dropdown data will come dynamically added rows.

i hope my question is understandable.

here is my Example Fiddle

**[Faild Fiddle Here](https://jsfiddle.net/joelshah/nrsoyg3m/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var i = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
    $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input name='cashpayment[" + i + "].name' type='text' placeholder='Enter code' id='cashacc_code' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><select class='form-control input-md' name='cashpayment[" + i + "].name' id='dynamic_sel'><option>Second dropdown</option></select></td><td><input name='cashpayment[" + i + "].name' type='text' placeholder='Enter your text here' class='form-control input-md' id='acc_narrat' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#accnarratModal' /> </td><td><input  name='cashdebt[" + i + "].name' type='text' placeholder='Amount 1' class='form-control input-md' id='cashdeb'data-action='sumDebit'></td><td><input  name='cashcredit[" + i + "].name' type='text' placeholder='Amount 2' data-action='sumCredit' class='form-control input-md' readonly></td>");
    // {/* <td>" + (i + 1) + "</td> */}
    $("#cashacc_sel").find("select").append().appendTo($("#dynamic_sel"));
    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
    // $('#cashacc_sel').append($('#dynamic_sel').html());
    i++;
  });
  $("#delete_row").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
      i--;
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-4" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
  <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0 input-group"> First Dropdown:</label>
  <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="cashacc" id="cashacc" required>
    <option value="">Choose an items</option>
    <option value="acc1">joe 1</option>
    <option value="acc2">joe 2</option>
    <option value="acc3">joe 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <tr style="background-color: #680779; color: #fff;">
            <th class="text-center">
              Code
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Name*
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Text*
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Initial amount*
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              First Payment
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left adRow">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default adRow" style="margin-right: 5px;">Delete Row</a>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="cashacc_code" name='cashacc_code' placeholder='Enter Code' class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" name="cashacc_sel" id="cashacc_sel">
                <option value="">Second dropdown</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_narrat" placeholder="Enter your text here" name="acc_narrat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accnarratModal" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" id="cashdeb" name='cashdebt' placeholder='Amount 1' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" id="cashcredit" name='cashcredit' placeholder='Amount 2' data-action="sumCredit" class="form-control" readonly />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='addr1'></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this link [Clik for more details](https://jsfiddle.net/9qknh0gu/)

> Html Code

```
<div class="form-group col-4" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">   <label class="col-sm-12 control-label p-sm-0 input-group"> First Dropdown:</label>   <select class="form-control selectsch_items" name="cashacc" id="cashacc" required>
    <option value="">Choose an items</option>
    <option value="acc1">joe 1</option>
    <option value="acc2">joe 2</option>
    <option value="acc3">joe 3</option>   </select> </div>

<div class="container">   <div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-md-12 column">
      <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
        <thead>
          <tr style="background-color: #680779; color: #fff;">
            <th class="text-center">
              Code
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Name*
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Text*
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              Initial amount*
            </th>
            <th class="text-center">
              First Payment
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <a id="add_row" class="btn btn-default pull-left adRow">Add Row</a><a id='delete_row' class="pull-right btn btn-default adRow" style="margin-right: 5px;">Delete Row</a>
          <tr id='addr0'>
            <td>
              <input type="text" id="cashacc_code" name='cashacc_code' placeholder='Enter Code' class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <select class="form-control" name="cashacc_sel" id="cashacc_sel">
                <option value="">Second dropdown</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="acc_narrat" placeholder="Enter your text here" name="acc_narrat" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#accnarratModal" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" id="cashdeb" name='cashdebt' placeholder='Amount 1' data-action="sumDebit" class="form-control" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <input type="number" id="cashcredit" name='cashcredit' placeholder='Amount 2' data-action="sumCredit" class="form-control" readonly />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id='addr1'></tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>   </div> </div>
```

> Jquery Code

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#cashacc_sel").html($('#cashacc').html());
  var i = 1;
  $("#add_row").click(function() {
  var oSelectedValue = $('#cashacc').val();
    $('#addr' + i).html("<td><input name='cashpayment[" + i + "].name' type='text' placeholder='Enter code' id='cashacc_code' class='form-control input-md'/></td><td><select class='form-control input-md' name='cashpayment[" + i + "].name' id='dynamic_sel'><option>Second dropdown</option></select></td><td><input name='cashpayment[" + i + "].name' type='text' placeholder='Enter your text here' class='form-control input-md' id='acc_narrat' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#accnarratModal' /> </td><td><input  name='cashdebt[" + i + "].name' type='text' placeholder='Amount 1' class='form-control input-md' id='cashdeb'data-action='sumDebit'></td><td><input  name='cashcredit[" + i + "].name' type='text' placeholder='Amount 2' data-action='sumCredit' class='form-control input-md' readonly></td>");
    // {/* <td>" + (i + 1) + "</td> */}
    $("#cashacc_sel").find("select").append().appendTo($("#dynamic_sel"));
    $('#tab_logic').append('<tr id="addr' + (i + 1) + '"></tr>');
    // $('#cashacc_sel').append($('#dynamic_sel').html());
     $("select[name='cashpayment[" + i + "].name']").html($('#cashacc option:not(:selected)'));
     $("#cashacc").html($('#cashacc_sel').html());
      $("#cashacc").val(oSelectedValue);
    i++;

  });
  $("#delete_row").click(function() {
    if (i > 1) {
      $("#addr" + (i - 1)).html('');
      i--;
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, and if i select **joe 1** from 1st dropdown, i dont want to show **joe 1** on 2nd dropdown.. remaining joe 2, joe 3 only show the second dropdown..

Comment: Ok, so you want dropdown option dynamic if I'm select option 1 in the first row then next row add only remaining option?

Comment: Yes, but not a first row, if I'm select option 1 in the first dropdown (outside of table dropdown) then the table dropdown add only remaining options..

Comment: Ok please correct me if you have select option 1 in outside of table then you add row so reming option add?

Comment: Please check updated code and for more details check this link https://jsfiddle.net/o2jrm369/

Comment: right sir, and can do small change, 1st row also wants to remaining options not for entire options, please modify and let me knw sir.

Comment: I believe the first row by default showing if you want we can set reming option in the drop-down change event if correct so we can move ahead.

Comment: its my requirement sir, so

Comment: Ok, we will do.

Comment: Sir, can you did?

Comment: Sure we do but need some time.